# I'm getting this huge error every time I try to Pip install Seaborn - anyone know why?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Like the title says... running into this when I try to pip install Seaborn, not sure why.

I had to cut out a lot of the result set to fit the character count limits. Think it was mostly erroneous to the issue at hand (hopefully).

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32>pip install seaborn
Collecting seaborn
  Using cached seaborn-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (283 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from seaborn) (1.19.3)
Collecting scipy>=1.0
  Downloading scipy-1.5.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (31.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 31.4 MB 6.4 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.23 in c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from seaborn) (1.1.4)
Collecting matplotlib>=2.2
  Using cached matplotlib-3.3.2.tar.gz (37.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.23->seaborn) (2020.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.23->seaborn) (2.8.1)
Collecting certifi>=2020.06.20
  Using cached certifi-2020.6.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10
  Downloading cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1
  Downloading kiwisolver-1.3.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (51 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 51 kB 212 kB/s
Collecting pillow>=6.2.0
  Downloading Pillow-8.0.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.1 MB ...
Collecting pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.3
  Downloading pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 67 kB 3.0 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas>=0.23->seaborn) (1.15.0)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for matplotlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: scipy, certifi, cycler, kiwisolver, pillow, pyparsing, matplotlib, seaborn
    Running setup.py install for matplotlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-soqvf_ui\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-soqvf_ui\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bwu9njh7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\matplotlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-soqvf_ui\matplotlib\
    Complete output (571 lines):

    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options; suppress output with --quiet.

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
      matplotlib: yes [3.3.2]
          python: yes [3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC
                      v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]]
        platform: yes [win32]
     sample_data: yes [installing]
           tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
          macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
```

-- Cutting out erroneous details (I think) to stay under the character limit

```
    UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\matplotlib\_version.py
    set build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\matplotlib\_version.py to '3.3.2'
    running build_ext
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    Extracting freetype-2.6.1.tar.gz
    Building freetype in build\freetype-2.6.1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-soqvf_ui\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-soqvf_ui\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bwu9njh7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\matplotlib' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 20.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Just noticed the visual c++ part of the error... only working with VS Code - do I need full fledged visual studio? Not sure why that would be  the case.

Comment: Instead of installing the build tools, you could also install `pipwin` and then use that to install pre-built wheels from Gholke's repository until Matplotlib has a wheel released for Python 3.9 on Windows themselves. See the duplicate.